# Editing LaunchImage Icon in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, splash-screen

I am trying to edit the LaunchImage icon [in my XCode Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c94QM.png) but for some reason I can't drag and drop an image of my choice on to the LaunchScreen storyboard. I am not sure how to import an image either. Something else that confuses me is that originally I was able to see an asset for "LaunchImage" under my "Assets" folder but as soon as I added an AppIcon, it disappeared. This is for a Flutter project for which I am trying to set up a splash screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an image that you want to show, for that you can drag & drop an image into the Assets folder or you can drag and drop an image directly under the Runner folder then in the LaunchScreen, add a proper constraint to an image view and then right-hand side there is an attribute inspector, you need to place name of your image into it as shown below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxSor.png

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you very much!